# POST parameters received as null in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, post, .net-core

I have this function in my `ControllerBase` controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddAsync([FromBody] MyObjClass myObj)
```

I'm trying to send POST function from UI to server. When I'm using `[FromBody]` attribute, it doesn't enter the function at all and the UI get timeout error. When I delete this attribute, it does enter but `myObj` is null. I also tried to add `[ApiController]` attribute to the controller but it didn't help.

I have also a GET function with `[FromQuery]` attribute and it works fine.

In the browser I can see the payload sent to the server and it looks totally fine. I also copied the payload data to postman and it worked! But directly from UI - It enters the function with null.

It's a new project so I also might have missing configurations.

Comment: > *it doesn't enter the function at all.* What response do you get?

Comment: Most likely it is how you craft the request. Can you show that code and the definition for MyObjClass?

Comment: @tymtam The UI gets gateway timeout

Comment: @Crowcoder I tried also with a simple string and a simple object to make sure it's not the problem

Comment: That doesn't convince me of anything. As written there is no way of knowing exactly what is wrong. Have you tried with Postman? Have you traced it with Fiddler?

Comment: Gateway Timeout is suspicious. You should get a 404 if it's not hitting the endpoint. Are you running locally?

Comment: not working both locally and test environment.

Comment: You should also write your UI code. The problem probably is in your Input naming of your form

Comment: I copied the payload from the UI to postman - postman works. So not a naming problem.

Comment: We still need to see your UI Code and the definition of `MyObjClass`. Are you seeing any other errors in the browser, like anything in the console?

Comment: If Postman works then there is a problem with how you craft the request. Are you GETting instead of POSTing? Are you omitting an important header, etc....? If you use Postman's code generation feature for HTTP and post it along with your c# we can probably spot the difference.

Comment: did you set headers in your request from UI?